# DNS (bind) : How do I redirect an http request to a different domain, based on the requested domain

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, bind, rewrite

I host my own DNS server and would like to be able to redirect links from within the DNS server so that redirection is seamless.

Example:  redirect all requests for www.yahoo.com to www.google.com.  I'd like to rewrite the parameters as well.

IE:  www.yahoo.com?search=asdf  -->  www.google.com?q=asdf

Is this better done through a proxy server?  I want to minimize the amount of custom configuration that must be done at the router level and put all the logic into the my DNS (or proxy) server.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something you can do with DNS. If you host the domain you want to redirect then Apache+Mod-rewrite would be my suggestion, if not, then a Squid proxy would be how I'd tackle the problem.

Bart.

Comment: Both are good suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, Bart.  Is it possible to redirect traffic through a proxy server at the router level (say a cheap linksys or netgear)?  I'd like to not have to configure each client browser individually.

Comment: You can put the proxy inline with the router or use DHCP to set it as the default gateway. Do a search on "Transparent Proxy" for other suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have Bind return a zone record that points to your server (named.conf):

```
zone "www.yahoo.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/yahoo.com.db";
};
```

/var/named/yahoo.com.db  :

```
 $TTL    604800
 *. IN  A   IPADDRESSOFYOURSERVERHERE
```

Then from your web server, you will have to create a DNS record that acts as yahoo.com. Once you have that, a simple apache redirect should be able to move all the traffic to google or wherever.